# Image background stretch entire table cell

Tags: html, css

What should be done if I want to set an image stretch exactly to fit table cell size?

I had a table with 1 row and 3 columns. Each column has 1 image. I tried to place properties of `width=33%, height=auto` but image display still distorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using css.

```
td table {
    background: url(path/to/background.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: hi Hemant,any chance to achieve the modification in html/ *.aspx ?

Comment: Hi, Sample Example may be this help you for table cell..                       
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
#mydiv img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>
<table id="mydiv" border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="33%"><img src="C:\Users\hemant.kothari\Desktop\hems.jpg"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Youd need to use **background-size : contain**, but be carefull with the proportion of the image and the size of your cells.

see the exemple below :

**HTML** :

```
<h2>
Test
</h2>

<table class="tab">
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS** :

```
.tab{
  border : 1px solid red;
}

.tab td
{
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;

  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-image: url('https://static.fnac-static.com/multimedia/Images/FR/NR/8a/c9/89/9030026/1540-1/tsp20171113114257/Figurine-Pixel-Pals-Light-Up-Capcom-Street-Fighter-Ryu.jpg');
   background-position: center; 
   background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marko, I tried code below in html :                                                          <body>
    <table class="tab">
       <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></td>
        <td><a class="active" href="#BUSINESS">ABOUT US</a></td>
        <td><a class="active" href="#PRODUCTS">OUR PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES</a></td>
        <td><a class="active" href="#CONTACT">CONTACT US</a></td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    
</body>

Comment: image can be displayed